# How to quickly determine if multiple places are within users vicinity - Google Places API

Tags: php, javascript, google-places-api

I am designing a web app where I need to determine which places listed in my DB are in the users driving distance.

Here is a broad overview of the process that I am currently using -

1. Get users current location via Google's map api
2. Run through each place in my database(approx 100) checking if the place is within the users driving distance using the google places api.  I return and parse the JSON file with PHP to see if any locations exist given the users coordinates.
3. If place is in users driving distance display top locations(limited to 20 by google places), other wise don't display

This process works fine when I am running through a handful of places, but running through 100 places is much slower, and makes 100 api calls.  With Google's current limit of 100,000 calls per day, this could become an issue down the road.

So is there a better way to determine which places in my database are within a users driving distance?  I do not want to keep track of addresses in my DB, I want to rely on Google for that.

Thanks.

Comment: What information do you have in your database? Lat Lng? Place name?

Comment: I am only storing place name, and some other details that are irrelevant.  So say for example Best Buy.  I want to be able to say, ok you live in Omaha Nebraska, there are these Best Buys near you.  The next place is Office Max, well there are no office Max's in Omaha, so dont display anything.  And keep going through all the places displaying only what is relevant to your location.

Comment: Well, this is the solution I have decided to use for the time being:  I have decided to only service the top 275 cities in the US(thats all cities over 100k pop).  I have a DB of the cities and their coordinates.  Each night I will run a script that will update the db with the number of places that are within that city's vicinity.  So I will be able to look up Phoenix AZ, and list all the places that have a count higher than 0.  If a user is not located in one of the top 275 cities, I will show them the closest city to their location.  I think this should work for my application.

Comment: Im not sure what type of script you are planing to run but if it automates places search request at set locations it would probably get flagged and your access to the API for that project discontinued. Just check the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) before implementing your solution.

Comment: (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.

Comment: I believe the above TOS section allows me to do what I am doing.  The only thing I am storing is the count on the number of objects returned from a google places api call.  So I have a MySQL table that stores Las Vegas, Best Buy, 5.  Las Vegas, Frys, 1 and so on.

Comment: Ok that sounds fine. Good luck with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula found here to calculate the distance between zip codes:

http://support.sas.com/kb/5/325.html

This is not precise (door-step to door-step) but you can calculate the distance from the user's zip code to the location's zip code.

Using this method, you won't even have to hit Google's API.

Answer (score -1):

I have an unconventional idea for you. This will be very, very odd when you think about it for the first time, as it does *exactly the opposite order* of what you will expect to do. However, you might get to see the logic.

In order to put it in action, you'll need a broad category of stuff that you want the user to see. For instance, I'm going to go with "supermarkets".

There is a wonderful API as part of google places called nearbySearch. Its true wonder is to allow you to rank places by distance. We will make use of this.

## Pre-requisites

- Modify your database and store the unique ID returned on nearbySearch places. This isn't against the ToS, and we'll need this
- Get a list of those IDs.

## The plan

When you get the user's location, query nearbySearch for your category, and loop through results with the following constraints:

- If the result's ID matches something in your database, you have that result. Bonus #1: it's sorted by distance ascending! Bonus #2: you already get the lat-loc for it!
- If the result's ID does not match, you can either silently skip it or use it and add it to your database. This means that you can quite literally update your database on-the-fly with little to no manual work as an added bonus.

When you have run through the request, you will have IDs that never came up in the results. Calculate the point-to-point distance of the furthest result in Google's data and you will have the max distance from your point. If this is too small, use the technique I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16059014/2167834) to do a compounded search.

The only requirement is: **you need to know roughly what you are searching for**. However, consider this: your normal query cycle takes you anywhere between 1 and 100 google Queries. My method takes 1 for a 50km radius. :-)

To calculate distances, you will need Haversine's formula rather than doing a zip code lookup, by the way. This has the added advantage of being truly international.

### Important caveats

This search method directly depends on the trade-off between the places you know about and the distance. If you are looking for less than 10km radii, use this method to only generate one request.

If, however, you have to do compounded searching, bear in mind that each request cycle will cost you 3N, where N is the number of queries generated on the last cycle. Therefore, if you only have 3 places in a 100km radius, it makes more sense to look up each place individually.

Comment: (Just to add - this *is* compatible with Google's ToS - the only thing you need to store is the unique ID referer)

Comment: Could the person who downvoted me actually say *why* they've done so?